# Removing decimal places in some columns and keeping them in others

Tags: python, pandas, format, decimal

Team,

I am trying to get rid of decimals in a few columns and keep them in others. Below is my pathetic attempt at coding.

I would like to get rid of the decimals in the RFW Tota, Hit Count, Cover Count, Tie Wins, and Tie Away. I would like to keep decimals, rounded to 2 places, in the hit ratio %, cover ratio %, tie ratio %, and Revenue.

```
    'RFW Total': [RFQ_count, Vol_RAMT, DV01],
                   'Hit Count': [hit_count, hit_count_volume, hit_count_DV01],
                    'Hit Ratio %': [hit_ratio_count * 100, hit_ratio_volume * 100, hit_ratio_DV01 * 100],
                    'Cover Count': [cover_plus_count, cover_plus_volume, cover_plus_DV01],
                    'Cover Ratio %': [(cover_plus_count / RFQ_count) * 100, (cover_plus_volume / Vol_RAMT) * 100, (cover_plus_DV01 / DV01) * 100],
                    'Tie Wins': [tie_win_count , tie_win_volume, tie_win_DV01],
                    'Tie Away': [tie_away_count, tie_away_volume, tie_away_DV01],
                    'Tie Ratio %': [tie_win_count / tie_away_count, tie_win_volume / tie_away_volume, tie_win_DV01 / tie_away_DV01],
                    'Revenue': [(rev_count).round(decimals=3), (rev_count / hit_count_volume).round(decimals=2), (rev_count*1000000 / hit_count_DV01)]}
index_labels=["Count", "Volume (R-AMT) *mm", "DV01"] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(DF_data, index=index_labels).round(decimals=2).style.format("{:,}")
# df1.style.format({'RFW Total': '{:,.1f}'.format, 'Hit Count': '{:,.1f}'.format, 'Hit Ratio %': '{:,.2f}'.format}
df1`
```

Comment: `df[column_names] = df[column_names].astype(int)`?

Comment: I am just not sure where that would go in the code. Still relatively new to this game.

Comment: I ended up converting to an integer, which solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Get it done with `astype` and `round`.

```py
columns_to_int = ['RFW Total', 'Hit Count', 'Cover Count', 'Tie Wins', 'Tie Away']
df = df.astype({col:'int' for col in columns_to_int})
columns_to_round = ['hit ratio %', 'cover ratio %', 'tie ratio %', 'Revenue']
df[columns_to_round] = df[columns_to_round].round(2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to put both into the same dataframe?

Comment: It is in the same dataframe ( `df` in your code ). You could check the result with `print(df)`.